# Can reptiles with legs shed their skin all at once?

Tags: creature-design, reptiles

I know snakes have an easier time and legs make things difficult.

Would this be impractical for riding lizards in a fantasy setting? Could one breed for a trait of a faster shedding process?

Comment: I would advise caution with skin-shedding. I remember a story where you're advised to be extra careful when handling the during 'shedding season', because snakes (for example, and the example in the story) see very poorly while shedding. Meaning, they would be easier to startle while shedding, and also poor mounts during that period.

Comment: Actually, yes, in my story the mount pitches the character off because her it is shedding. All the texts I've read on this say that lizards and other reptiles change behavior when they are moulting.

Comment: I don't think there is an SE suitable for this question, but I'm afraid it's not about worldbuilding but rather about normal Earth fauna and, as such, off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Separatrix I really want more information about those normal Earth riding lizards. That would be pretty sweet.

Comment: @AndyD273, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6db_6BAK_M

Comment: @Separatrix Very interesting! I do disagree that questions about Earth life can't be about world building. Alternate Earth history can be world building. Earth actually happens to be a world. We are here to help people build imaginary worlds, even if those imaginary worlds happen to be extremely similar to Earth in many ways. While it could use a better title and tags, this question is not off topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alligator lizards shed their skin all at once, but they might not make great riding lizards as they have short legs. Breeding for a shorter shedding process might make sense, but also providing tools and equipment might help. Keeping the skin damp, providing rough surfaces to rub off old skin, and providing proper nutrition all help lizards shed properly.

See here for a photo of the Alligator Lizard shedding. 
http://curbstonevalley.com/blog/?p=1583
"they shed their skin in a single intact piece by essentially turning it inside out as they crawl out of it."